# jquery colorbox open links in popup window

Tags: jquery, popup, colorbox

I'm using Jquery colorbox to implement a popup windows.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.colorbox({innerWidth:"600px", innerHeight:"520px", iframe:true,href:"/notice.php"}); 
});
</script>
```

In the popup php file, there are some links which linked to other pages. When I click those links, the new page will displayed in the popup window. **I want to open the new page in the base page but not the small popup window.**

Any Suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Don

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you have

```
iframe:true
```

It must be

```
iframe:false
```

An iframe is basically just another window frame inside a document, and acts pretty much like a browser tab. That's why your page is opening in the popup.